# Instance variable s3 accessed in class method

Tags: objective-c

i m uploading my images in amazon s3 bucket.i m writing my code in a seperate class Amazons3,
I m getting an error instance variable s3 accessed in class method.how to solve this error .i m creating a constructor for the variable initialization.could you guys help me out.

```
-(id) init
   {
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {

        if(self.s3 == nil)
        {
            // Initial the S3 Client.
            self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

 +(void)uploadImage:(Products *)product
 {

    NSData *uploadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[Util getFilePathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ios.mp4",product.productImageUrl]]];
    S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",product.productImageUrl] inBucket:BUCKET_NAME];
    por.contentType = @"application/octet-stream";
    por.cannedACL   = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
    por.data = uploadData;
    S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [s3 putObject:por];
    if(putObjectResponse.error !=nil)
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showCheckErrorMessage:) withObject:putObjectResponse.error  waitUntilDone:NO];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uploadImage:` probably must be an instance method. Change its signature to `-(void)uploadImage:(Products *)product`.

Your error is quite self-explaining : an instance attribute (per-object) cannot be accessed in a class method (per-class). You need an instanced object to access an object attribute ;)